# Extract string between forward slashes using regex

Tags: regex

I have a url pattern that takes the following form:

1. https://www.facebook.com/foo123/photos/1234/
2. https://www.facebook.com/foo123/photos/a.123/1234/

In this case I need to extract string after /photos/

eg:

1. In case 1 the valid string is 1234
2. in case 2 the valid string is 1234

I drafted the the following regex but it fails on case 2

```
\/photos\/([^\/\?]+)
```

so essentially grabbing everything after /photos/ followed by / ?

I need a simple regex that can also work in case 2

so the logic is:

the string is either found after /photos/ or one level after /photos/. The string only contains digits. If the string if found after /photos/ it would end with /. if it is found one level after /photos/ it would also end with /

Comment: Do you need just digits? `\/photos\/[^\/?]*?(\d+)`? Why do you include `$` into the negated character class? Maybe you wanted to use `#` instead of `$`?

Comment: In the second case I need 1234, this string comes after /a.123/ and yes the string contains only digits. I have edited the question not to include $

Comment: What language are you using for this?

Comment: @CyberPunk Also, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the digit chunk after any chars other than `/`, `?` and digits:

```
\/photos\/(?:.*?\/)?(\d+)(?![^\/])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hqo9Be/2).

*Details*:

- `\/photos\/` - a `/photos/` string
- `(?:.*?\/)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars as few as possible and then a `/` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?![^\/])` - end of string or `/`.

Comment: In case https://www.facebook.com/foo123/photos/a.123/1234/ it would extract 123. The valid string is 1234